# how to use Ajax to send query by this method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-blade

I can not send an Ajax request in this way
found a suitable form for the site
https://github.com/codrops/MinimalForm
 and try to send data without refreshing the page
what am i doing wrong? need something like form.submit(){}?

form

```
<form id="theForm" class="simform" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="simform-inner">
                    <ol class="questions">
                        @foreach($answers as $answer)
                    <li>
                        <span><label for="q">{{ $answer->answer }}</label></span>
                        <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox1" style="display:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="{{$answer->id}}" id="checkbox1" checked name="id"  data-toggle="checkbox" >
                        </label>
                        <input id="q" name="word" type="text"/>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
                    </ol><!-- /questions -->
                    <button class="submit" type="submit">Send answers</button>

            </form><!-- /simform -->
```

js

```
<script src="/tests/js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="/tests/js/stepsForm.js"></script>
<script>
    var theForm = document.getElementById( 'theForm' );

    new stepsForm( theForm, {
        onSubmit : function( form ) {
            // hide form
            classie.addClass( theForm.querySelector( '.simform-inner' ), 'hide' );
            var query = "word=" + $("input[name=word]").val() +
                    "&id=" + $("input[name=id]").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : "http://example.com/frontend/tests/elementary-2/check",
                data : query,
                cache: false,

                dataType : "json",

                success : function(msg){console.log(msg);

                    if (msg['msg'] == true){
                        sweetAlert("Good job!", "some", "success");
                    }else {
                        sweetAlert("Oops...", "some", "error");
                    }

                }

            });

        }
    } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put return false in your form

```
<form id="theForm" class="simform" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return false;">
```

Your ajax is actually executing, but the form is also making a non-ajax request by default. return false will prevent the form from submitting with the default behavior.

Comment: this does not solve the problem, the fact is that I ask for advice how to properly submit the form, sorry for my english((

Comment: I have removed `onsubmit="return false;"`

data is sent only to the last INPUT
how to send Each time you press enter data from INPUT?

Answer (score 0):

ok if you asked for advice how to submit a form via ajax then here is an example-

```
        $(document).on("click", ".submit", function () {
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "your/url",
                    data: {your:data},
                    success: function(data) {

   //and from data parse your json data and show error message in the modal
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                        if(obj!=null)
                            {                             
                                $('#mssg').html(obj['message']);
                            }
                    }});
                 });
```

Comment: you probably misunderstood me, I know how to send data via Ajax, I ask Council of in this case to send the request.
you watched code ?

Comment: actually you made your question a little bit confusing, you asked that you can't send an ajax request. are you getting any error or something?

Comment: This is the problem nor the error did not occur. in this form when you press the enter the second point comes before the second point will I need to send the value of the INPUT for verification and return true or false

Comment: now tell me from where you found `var query = "word=" + $("input[name=email]").val() +  "&id=" + $("input[name=id]").val();` in your form there are no input field named email and id !

Comment: What about email sorry, typo, but id there by default cheked

Comment: `<label class="checkbox" for="checkbox1" style="display:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="{{$answer->id}}" id="checkbox1" checked name="id"  data-toggle="checkbox" >
                        </label>
                        <input id="q" name="word" type="text"/> `

Comment: No! why should I apply here if all would work?! :/
I'm trying to do, and when you move to the next stage was to send the request Ajax, look for the form itself, there is a link in the description